# Objective-C instance variables?

Tags: objective-c

I'm sure my confusion here is just a result of being stuck in a "Java mindset" and not understanding how Obj-C differs in this case.

In Java, I can declare a variable in a class, like this, and each *instance* of that class will have it's own:

```
MyClass {

  String myVar;

  MyClass() {
    // constructor
  }
}
```

In Obj-C I tried to do the same thing by declaring a variable only in the .m file like this:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

NSString *testVar;

@end
```

My expectation here was that this variable has a scope limited to this class.  So I created a second class (identical):

```
#import "MySecondClass.h"

@implementation MySecondClass

NSString *testVar;

@end
```

What I'm seeing (and has me baffled) is that changing the variable in one class, affects the value seen in the other class.  In fact, if I set a breakpoint, and then "Jump to Definition" of the variable, it takes me to th

I've created an extremely small Xcode project that demonstrates the problem [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/481022/TestIvar.zip).

Comment: Objective-C is more like C/C++ than Java.  Java is relatively unique in that it doesn't have separate declaration and implementation files but puts everything in one file.  In Objective-C you declare the instance fields in the @interface section of your .h file.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Change this:

```
@implementation MyClass

NSString *testVar;

@end
```

to:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    NSString *testVar;
}

// methods go here

@end
```

and you'll get what you expected.

As you had it, you are actually creating a global variable. The two global variables were combined into one by the linker which is why both changed when you set one. The variable in curly braces will be a proper (and private) instance variable.

Edit: After being downvoted for no apparent reason, I thought I'd point out the "old" way of doing things, and the new way.

The old way:

SomeClass.h

```
@interface SomeClass : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITextField *_textField;
    BOOL _someBool;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL someBool;

// a few method declarations

@end
```

SomeClass.m

```
@implementation SomeClass

@synthesize someBool = _someBool;

// the method implementations

@end
```

Now the new and improved way with the modern Objective-C compiler:

SomeClass.h

```
@interface SomeClass : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL someBool;

// a few method declarations

@end
```

SomeClass.m

```
@interface SomeClass () <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end

@implementation SomeClass {
    UITextField *_textField;
}

// the method implementations

@end
```

The new way has several advantages. The primary advantage is that none of the implementation specific details about the class appear in the .h file. A client has no need to know what delegates the implementation needs. The client has no need to know what ivars I use. Now, if the implementation needs a new ivar or it needs to use a new protocol, the .h file doesn't change. This mean less code gets recompiled. It cleaner and much more efficient. It also makes for easier editing. When I'm editing the .m file and realize I need a new ivar, make the change in the same .m file I'm already editing. No need to swap back and forth.

Also note the implementation no longer needs an ivar or `@synthesize` for the property.

Comment: I would guess it's because you don't describe the canonical form of @interface/@implementation.  What you show is technically allowed but hardly ever used and could be disastrously confusing to a newbie.

Comment: @HotLicks What I show is the new preferred approach. There's no reason to put private ivars in the .h file anymore. Not with the modern LLVM compiler. Beginners should learn the new way, not the old way.

Comment: @HotLicks I edited my answer to point out the old and new ways to code this.

Comment: Do you know what's the difference between your new SomeClass.m and code below:
~ /interface SomeClass () <UITextFieldDelegate>
~ /property UITextField *_textField;
~ /end
~ /implementation SomeClass {
~ }
~ // the method implementations
~ /end

Comment: @maddy, what is the distinction between the declaration of the global variable in the implementation **(as appears in the question and the first code block of this answer)** and declaring a property in the implementation **(which is not allowed)**.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want (unless you're using a very old OS and compiler) is to just use property syntax. I.e.:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

// method declarations here ...

@property (copy) NSString*    myVar;

// ... or here.

@end
```

This will do what you intended to do. This will implicitly synthesize an instance variable and a getter/setter pair for this variable. If you manually wanted to create the instance variable (you generally don't need that unless you need your code to work on very old MacOS versions), this is what the above code does under the hood to create the ivar:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString*    _myVar;
}

// method declarations here.

@end
```

Note the curly braces, which tell the compiler that this is not just a global variable somewhere in between the methods, but actually an instance variable that belongs to this object.

If you are creating the property only for internal use and don't want clients of your class to mess with it, you can hide this away a little bit in everything but the oldest ObjC compilers by using a *class extension* which "continues" the class declaration from the header, but can be placed separate from it (so usually in your implementation file). A class extension looks like a category without a name:

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (copy) NSString*    myVar;

@end
```

And you can either put your property declaration in there, or even ivar declarations (again wrapped in curly brackets). You can even declare the same property as `readonly` in the class interface, and then re-declare it identical, but as `readwrite` in the extension, so that clients only read it, but your code can change it.

Note that, if you didn't use ARC (that is, you've switched off the default of Automatic Reference Counting), you would have to set all your properties to `nil` in your `dealloc` method (unless they're set to `weak` or `assign` of course).

NB - All the above are `@interface` sections. Your actual code will go in separate `@implementation` sections. This is so you can have header files (`.h`) you can hand off to your class's clients that just contain the portions you intend them to use, and hide away implementation details in the implementation file (`.m`) where you can change them without having to worry someone might have accidentally used them and you'll break other code.

PS - Note that `NSStrings` and other objects that you want the immutable flavor of, but that also exist in a mutable flavor (i.e. `NSMutableString`) should always be `copy` properties, because that will turn an NSMutableString into an NSString so that nobody on the outside can change the mutable string underneath you. For all other object types, you generally use `strong` (or `retain` if not ARC). For your class's owner (e.g. its delegate) you usually use `weak` (or `assign` if not ARC).

Answer (score -1):

In Java

```
MyClass {

  String myVar;
  MyClass() {
    // constructor
  }
}
```

In Objective-c

```
MyClass.h

@interface MyClass : NSObject{

      NSString* str; // Declaration
}
@end

MyClass.m

@implementation MyClass

  -(void)initializieTheString
  {
     //Defination 
  }

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

In objective-c, you define the variable as private by doing like so

```
MyClass.h

@interface MyClass : NSObject{

      NSString* _myTestVar; // Declaration
}
@end
```

and refer to it in the implementation class by doing like so
MyClass.m

```
#import "MyClass.h";

@implementation MyClass

  -(void)initializieTheString
  {
     _myTestVar= @"foo"; //Initialization

  }

@end
```

Comment: Do not declare private ivars in the public header file. While valid, it's a bad idea. See my answer for more details.