# Why is the UIDatePicker value null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I have this code which adds a UIDatepicker (datePicker) when the UITextField (dateDue) is tapped:

In the viewDidLoad:

```
// Initiate datepicker and assign to due date
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
_dueDate.inputView = datePicker;
```

It works great, but I can't seem to get the date value in the changedDate function, it keeps returning null:

```
- (void) dateChanged:(id)sender{
    // Add the date to the dueDate text field
    NSLog(@"Date changed: %@", datePicker.date);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `dateChanged:` method you are accessing a variable named `datePicker`. Is this an instance variable?

Assuming it is, you never set it. In your `viewDidLoad` you have a local variable named `datePicker` that you use but that is different from the instance variable with the same name.

In `viewDidLoad`, change:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
```

to:

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
```

That will fix it.

You should also change your `dateChanged:` method to:

```
- (void) dateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)picker {
    // Add the date to the dueDate text field
    NSLog(@"Date changed: %@", picker.date);
}
```

Comment: WHen I change the code I get errors: "Use of undeclared identifier 'datePicker'; did you mean '_datePicker'?"

Comment: Do you have a property for your date picker? If so, use `self.datePicker`.

Comment: In the .h file? No I don't, because it is created programatically

Comment: Then what `datePicker` variable was being accessed in your `dateChanged:` method?

Comment: Not sure, but I synthesized the datPicker var and that seemed to do it. I thought by having the code "UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];" that would make the datePicker var available everywhere.

Comment: No, that just creates a local variable. It will only be available with the curly braces it is declared. You need an instance variable (either an explicit instance variable or a property).

Comment: I understand, I didn't consider the variable scope. Can I create a property in the h file, even if the UI element is created in the viewDidLoad. Does adding "@synthesize datePicker = datePicker;" make it a global var and is it safe?

Comment: Do not put anything in the .h. What you want is something private, not public. Whether you use a private property or a private instance variable is up to you. But which ever you choose should be declared in the .m file. And if you do use a property, do not bother with the `@synthesize` line. That hasn't been needed for quite some time now.

Comment: When I remove it, it stops working? How do I make datePicker a property instead?

Comment: Remove what from where? Did you declare the instance variable in the .m file? Did you add the ivar to the `@implementation { }` block?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48148/discussion-between-peter-stuart-and-rmaddy)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263229/objective-c-instance-variables-newbie/13263345#13263345