# How to access already initialised node within another method SpriteKit

Tags: ios, initialization, sprite-kit

In an application I have, I initialise a SKSpriteNode (Ball) the `didMoveToView` method. I have a method that picks up on swipes up (That works fine, I tested it).

When that is called, it calls a method called `[self jump];` 
In this method, I want it to run a few actions using the SKSpriteNode, `Ball`.

I used to know, but I have forgotten the code that allows you to access already initialised nodes. Say if I was going to write `[Ball runAction:myAction];`
, the compiler will replace 'Ball' with '_Ball'.

How can I manipulate the SKSpriteNode 'Ball' within another method? 
I don't think that I need to add any code but if it helps I will comply.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to store a reference to the ball sprite in an `@property` - then you can refer to it as `self.ball` - Don't use upper case letters for properties/variables - only for classes and don't use _ to access properties unless you know why you are doing it

Comment: Create a class property http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695980/how-do-i-declare-class-level-properties-in-objective-c or an instance variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263229/objective-c-instance-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a class property for ball to access it everywhere.

```
 @property (nonatomic,strong) SKSpriteNode *ball
```

You can use `self.ball` to access the ball in every method.

```
self.ball = //SKSpriteNode initialize
[self addChild:self.ball]
// Add Child
```

`SKNodes` can also be searched by using the **unique name** of its children.

For example you can set

```
// Initialise
ball.name = @"Ball"
// Add Child
```

Then the SKScene can be searched using the function `childWithName:`

```
SKSpriteNode *ball = [self childNodeWithName:@"Ball"]
```

The first method is easier in your case.

Comment: It comes up with a warning, that I am initialising a SKSpriteNode as an SKNode

Comment: It works now. I don't know how but the warning is gone ... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments you could keep a pointer to the ball node, however another way could be to use the **name** property of **SKNode**.

When you instantiate the ball node assign the **name** property with a string identifier -

```
SKSpriteNode *ball = // create instance here
ball.name = @"TheBall";// set its name
[self addChild:ball];// add to scene and forget about it
```

Whenever you need to access it from within your `SKScene` subclass use -

```
SKSpriteNode *sameBall = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"TheBall"];// don't forget the typecast
```

Now you can perform whatever actions you need to on the ball node.

An interesting read is the section on *Searching The Node Tree* found in the [SKNode Class Reference by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW74).