# C function accessing private ivar of Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801976/mixing-c-functions-in-an-objective-c-class/802059#comment10299203_828943):

> C functions inside @implementation blocks have the unique property of
>   being able to access private and protected ivars directly. Thus, from
>   my own experience, it's become a strong idiom to place C functions
>   that "belong" to a class inside the corresponding implementation.

My code, defining a private instance variable in the implementation only as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13263345/3758484):

With the brackets:

```
@implementation ViewController{
MyTest *tt;
}

void testf(){
    NSLog(@"hello back from c++ into obj c land");
    [tt testcf: 5];
}

...
```

Will not build; the compiler indicates that `tt` in `testf` is undeclared. If I remove the brackets, then the C function works fine.

But... if I remove the brackets, do I understand that actually this is no longer an instance variable, but sneakily it is a global variable, disconnected from the class, despites its placement in the `@implementation`? It would appear that this is indeed true, since I can do this as the end:

```
@end

void testf2(){
    NSLog(@"hello back from c++ into obj c land");
    [tt testcf: 5];
}
```

And the compiler does not contain about `tt` being out of scope. So -- how to declare a private instance variable in an implementation and have it truly be an instance variable, but also have a C function be able to access it? For the purposes of this question, I am trying to get this to work based on the linked comments/answers without using the `id` pointer of the object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass a reference to `self` to the C-function:

```
void testf(ViewController *vc){
    NSLog(@"hello back from c++ into obj c land");
    [vc->tt testcf: 5];
}
```

and call it like this:

```
- (void)someMethodInViewController
{
    testf(self);
}
```

However it's not clear why you are using C-functions at all.

Comment: I am writing a cross-platform library in C++ with a C API and I do not wish to  use any Objective-C++ and have everything go through the C API.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how that will work.  Using Objective-C++ is critical to integrating C++ and Objective-C.

Comment: I definitely disagree. Objective-C++ makes things easier, but Objective-C itself interacts with all sorts of C APIs, and there is no reason it could not also do so with such an API that has its implementation in C++, since the implementation and the interface are two different things. It's not much different than using Swift instead of Objective-C to interact with the same API in C.

Comment: Well cross-platform libraries written in C++ don't generally have a C-API, so that's kinda confusing.