# What does the {} after @interface in .h file mean?

Tags: objective-c

For example I was looking at [CHMutableDictionary.h](https://github.com/quinntaylor/CHDataStructures/blob/master/source/CHMutableDictionary.h)

```
@interface CHMutableDictionary : NSMutableDictionary {
    CFMutableDictionaryRef dictionary; // A Core Foundation dictionary.
}

- (id) initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems;

- (NSUInteger) count;
- (NSEnumerator*) keyEnumerator;
- (id) objectForKey:(id)aKey;
- (void) removeAllObjects;
- (void) removeObjectForKey:(id)aKey;
- (void) setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id)aKey;

@end
```

And it curly brackets `CFMutableDictionaryRef dictionary`. But in the [Objective-C guide Properties Control Access to an Object’s Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html) it doesn't make any mention of using `{}` in interfaces

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;

@end
```

So I was just wondering what variables defined in `{}` in interfaces of `.h` files mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare instance variables inside the curly braces.

But it's bad form to put them in the .h file. Instance variables should be private, not public. So they do not belong in the public .h file.

There is lots of old Objective-C code that doesn't follow these more modern conventions. Don't write new code using those very outdated conventions.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13263345/1226963 for some modern examples.